# In Memory Serialization using protocol buffer between c++ and c#

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to serialize data in c++ using protocol buffer and receive it in c# but In Memory i.e do not want to write data to a file. 
I have gone through the sample and references of protocol buffer but not able to find a way around. is there any sample which I can refer.

Comment: What does mean for you "In Memory" and not through the file? In Linux even when you use so called "shared memory", operating system still creates a file for that purpose. Can you please specify more precisely your requirement? Because for IPC you can use a lot of tools: ZMQ, `boost::interprocess`, but in most cases you will end up writing to a file.

Comment: by In Memory I mean within a single process itself.

Comment: But you wrote in the question that you communicate between the apps written in C++ and C#. So it cannot be a single process.The question remains unclear to me.

Comment: @Ptaq666 You can have code written in C# and C++ in the same process easily enough. Why one would use a byte array of sorts instead of just exchanging the data structures directly is pretty weird though.